# How to recommend top 10 products in Spark ALS for all the users?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How can we get top 10 recommended products in PySpark. I understand there are methods like recommendProducts to recommend products for a single user and predictAll to predict rating for the {user,item} pair. But is there a efficient way i can output the top 10 items for each user for all the users?

Comment: With Scala you can use `recommendProductsForUser` but at this moment this feature is not exposed through PySpark API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote this function which multiplies user features and product features by partitions so that it gets distributed then it gets the ratings for each product by user and sorts them by rating and outputs the list of 8 top recommended products.

```
#Collect product feature matrix
 productFeatures = bestModel.productFeatures().collect() 
 productArray=[]
 productFeaturesArray=[]
 for x in productFeatures:
    productArray.append(x[0])
    productFeaturesArray.append(x[1])  
 matrix=np.matrix(productFeaturesArray)
 productArrayBroadCast=sc.broadcast(productArray)
 productFeaturesArraybroadcast=sc.broadcast(matrix.T)

 def func(iterator):
      userFeaturesArray = []
      userArray = []
      for x in iterator:
          userArray.append(x[0])
          userFeaturesArray.append(x[1])
          userFeatureMatrix = np.matrix(userFeaturesArray)
          userRecommendationArray = userFeatureMatrix*(productFeaturesArraybroadcast.value)
          mappedUserRecommendationArray = []
          #Extract ratings from the matrix
          i=0
          for i in range(0,len(userArray)):
              ratingdict={}
              j=0
              for j in range(0,len(productArrayBroadcast.value)):
                   ratingdict[str(productArrayBroadcast.value[j])]=userRecommendationArray.item((i,j))
                   j=j+1
              #Take the top 8 recommendations for the user
              sort_apps=sorted(ratingdict.keys(), key=lambda x: x[1])[:8]
              sort_apps='|'.join(sort_apps)
              mappedUserRecommendationArray.append((userArray[i],sort_apps))
              i=i+1
      return [x for x in mappedUserRecommendationArray]


recommendations=model.userFeatures().repartition(2000).mapPartitions(func)
```

Answer (score 4):

PySpark >= 1.6.0 provides [MatrixFactorizationModel.recommendProductsForUsers](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/_modules/pyspark/mllib/recommendation.html#MatrixFactorizationModel.recommendProductsForUsers):

```
>> model.recommendProductsForUsers(3).take(2)
[(1,
  (Rating(user=1, product=2975, rating=0.003626774788608227),
   Rating(user=1, product=1322, rating=0.002494393082165332),
   Rating(user=1, product=8746, rating=0.002176665942528324))),
 (2,
  (Rating(user=2, product=4060, rating=0.011020947406565042),
   Rating(user=2, product=2332, rating=0.009479319983658458),
   Rating(user=2, product=1979, rating=0.004587168057824856)))]
```

Comment: In the case of implicit ratings — where users don't explicitly rate products — you might not want to filter out test data.

Comment: But the user has already performed an action (view, purchase, whatever) on that item, we would you want to recommend it to him/her?

Comment: We can't presume that any "rated" item must be removed from the results. A user interacting with an item may be a strong indicator that they like the item and that it should be recommended to them, whether or not they've seen it before. Business logic pertaining to the recommendations, such as filtering out certain items, is probably best done outside of the recommendation engine. Other APIs let us do this, such as [predictAll](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel.predictAll).